# Reusable Modules in Web Development

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Just looking for some big picture development/design advice.  I'm looking to design a website using Bootstrap 4 as a CSS codebase to help with site design.  Is there an easy framework where things that I create can be applied in a modular sense?  So if I change the NavBar in a central location, I don't need to look at each page in the site?  What should I look into learning in order to code in this manner, rather than copying and pasting my HTML to every page that I create.

Thanks!

Comment: use any mvc technologies

Comment: It's possible with simple "php", but if you already familiar with php you can take a look into "laravel php framework"

Comment: In PHP you can create a template such as `header.php` then you will put all your header HTML codes there and for every page you have you can write `<?php include 'header.php'; ?>`. See https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp for reference.

Comment: I thought PHP was considered archaic and poor form these days - is this still the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are unfamiliar with backend coding, or you do not have access to it, you may want to consider Javascript.

In your source code, you would move everything between `<nav`> and `</nav>` to a separate source (let's call it navigation.html). Using Javascript you can load navigation.html whenever a page is loaded.

In the (near) future, an [HTML import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/HTML_Imports) may become available.

```
window.onload = () => {
  nav = document.getElementsByTagName("nav")[0]; // First nav element in the document
  fetch('navigation.html')    // Modern browsers only
    .then(function(html) {    // Receive navigation.html content
      nav.append(html);       // Insert content of navigation.html into <nav></nav>
    });
}
```